# C++ Question about .append() vs .push_back() for Strings and Characters (Beginner Question)

Tags: c++, string, append, character, push-back

I have a question regarding which functions work for appending strings.
In this particular code, it asks: Given string givenInput on one line and character extension on a second line, append extension to givenInput.
Ex: If the input is:
`Hello !`
then the output is:
`Hello!`

The code I have so far

```
int main() {
    string givenInput;
    char extension;

    getline(cin, givenInput);
    cin >> extension;
    
    // this is the line of code I am allowed to edit and have come up with:
    givenInput.push_back(extension);
    
    cout << givenInput << endl;
```

Why is it that `givenInput.push_back(extension);` works but then `givenInput.append(extension);` does not?
I thought that append() works with types such as strings, characters, integers, etc..., but when I use the append function, it gives an error...
I actually originally had `givenInput = givenInput.append(extension);` , but there was an error, which then led me to do just `givenInput.append(extension);`  (which also had an error), which then finally left me to try `givenInput.push_back(extension);`  which ended up working.

In this other prompt, it asks: Assign secretID with firstName, a space, and lastName.
Ex: If firstName is John and lastName is Doe, then output is: John Doe

I have:

```
int main() {
   string secretID;
   string firstName;
   string lastName;

   cin >> firstName;
   cin >> lastName;
   
   // this is the line of code I can edit
   secretID = firstName.append(" " + lastName);

   cout << secretID << endl;
```

Why in this case would the append function work, but it wouldn't work for the other example?
Is it simply due to the fact that lastName is a string, while extension is a char?
Also, why is it that something like `secretID = firstName.append();` works for this second example while something like `givenInput = givenInput.append(extension)` does not work for the first example?

I know this is A LOT of text, but if someone could please explain the rules behind this, that would be greatly appreciated, as it would clear up my confusion!!

***Note: I do understand that something like `givenInput = givenInput + extension;` as well as
`secretID = firstName + " " + lastName;` would work for both examples, but I guess I am asking simply about the rules that apply for the append() and push_back() functions, regardless of if they aren't the most optimal to use for these cases.

Comment: If you look at the manual for [`append`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append), you'll see that it doesn't have an overload (i.e. a version) accepting a single `char`. For whatever reason. Also `append` returns a reference to the same string, so `a = b.append(c);` means `b.append(c); a = b;`.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than trying functions out through trial and error, you could look at what member functions `std::string` provides:

- [See reference for `std::string::append`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append)
- [See reference for `std::string::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back)

Notice that `append` doesn't have any overload that takes just one character.
If you really wanted to use it, you could theoretically call:

```cpp
givenInput.append(1, extension);
```

... but that is rather pointless, because you could write:

```cpp
givenInput.push_back(extension);
// or
givenInput += extension;
```

In the second example, you have used `append` correctly, because it does have an overload (2) that accepts a `std::string`.

When in doubt, just use [`operator+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) because it works with both characters and strings:

```cpp
secretID += ' ';
secretID += lastName;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the class `std::string` (or class template `std::basic_string`) there is no overloaded member function `append` that has only one parameter of the type `char` (or `charT`). For characters there is the following overloaded member function `append`

```
basic_string& append(size_type n, charT c);
```

So you could write for example

```
givenInput.append(1, extension);
```

The set of overloaded member functions `append` is similar to the constructors of the class `std::string`: in general member functions `append` have similar lists of parameters as constructors. Consider for example the following constructor

```
basic_string(size_type n, charT c, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

As you can see the above function append has the same parameters as the first two parameters of the constructor.

Pay attention to that instead of this statement

```
givenInput.push_back(extension);
```

you could just write

```
givenInput += extension;
```